# Guidance with using classes/constructors

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am writing a program that asks the user for two vectors (with a force and magnitude) and then returns the sum of the two vectors. I'm not really looking for someone to just give me the code, but I really just need some guidance on how to proceed. I feel like I really don't understand the implementation of classes/constructors yet and so I'm pretty sure I'm doing things incorrectly, or at least inefficiently. NOTE: I hope it's obvious I'm not finished. I'm just having kind of a "coder's block" :P

```
#include "std_lib_facilities_4.h"

class Physics_vector {
    double force, magnitude, x, y, f, m;
    vector<double> final;
    vector<double> v;

    public:
    Physics_vector(double x, double y) :force(x), magnitude(y) {};
    void set_vector(double f, double m);
    int get_vector(vector<double> final);
    double add_physics_vector();
};

void Physics_vector::set_vector(double f, double m)
{
    f = force;
    m = magnitude;
    vector<double> final;
    final.push_back(f);
    final.push_back(m);
}

int Physics_vector::get_vector(vector<double> final)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        cout << final[i] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Howdy!" << '\n';
    cout << "This program adds together two vectors."
         << endl;
    cout << "First, enter in the force and magnitude of your first vector." 
         << "\nExample: 4 7." << endl;

    double user_force, user_magnitude, force, magnitude;
    cin >> user_force >> user_magnitude;
    Physics_vector first(user_force, user_magnitude);
    first.set_vector(force, magnitude);

    cout << "Next, enter in the force and magnitude of your second vector."
         << endl;
    cin >> user_force >> user_magnitude;
    Physics_vector second(user_force, user_magnitude);
}
```

EDIT: Ok, so I changed my code a little to make it cleaner (if it's not tell me). But now my problem is function calls.

```
class Physics_vector {
public:
    Physics_vector(double x = 0, double y = 0) :x(x), y(y) {}
    double get_vector(double x, double y);
private:
    double x, y;
};

double Physics_vector::get_vector(double x, double y)
{
    return x;
    return y;
}

double add_physics_vector(vector<double> vect_1, vector<double> vect_2)
{
    return 0.0;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Howdy! Please enter your first vector (direction and magnitude) ."
        << "\nExample: 1 2." << endl;
    double user_direction = 0;
    double user_magnitude = 0;
    cin >> user_direction >> user_magnitude;
    Physics_vector(user_direction, user_magnitude);
    //get_vector(...aaaand I'm stuck...
}
```

How do I get `get_vector(double x, double y)` to use the `x` and `y` values from `Physics_vector()` as it's arguments? I'm sure this seems so rudimentary to most of you; I hate that I'm having so much trouble with classes...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you're getting the effect you want, you're doing things fine. However I'm not really sure if that's the case. As far as I know, a [vector in physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) is a body having magnitude and direction.

If you're trying to design a simple `Physics_vector` class, I would probably stick with:

```
class Physics_vector{
    double x, y;

public:
    Physics_vector(double x, double y);
};
```

Or, in case you want to operate in N-dimensional space:

```
class Physics_vector{
   unsigned int dimensions; // Optional, same as magnitudes.size();
   vector<double> magnitudes;

public:
   Physics_vector(unsigned int dimensions, ...);
}
```

Or, in the last case - simply use [templates](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm) (possibly [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) if you're operating in C++11).

Comment: You probably shouldn't leave the constructor private.

Comment: @Marian Thanks for pointing that out. Making it `public` probably will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, classes are used to represent a single unit of data--in your case, a vector (in the physics sense). The class itself should ideally contain only the member variables it needs to hold the data it represents and (only if absolutely necessary) any other pieces of data its member functions require to work. It appears you are trying to implement a vector that has two dimensions, so we'll start from there.

First, we need to determine the minimum required member data the class needs to perform its function. I find that thinking too hard about this does nothing but make the class overly complicated. In physics, a vector in two dimensions can be represented in multiple ways, but the most common is the Cartesian form (x, y). So, in order to implement this all that is required are those two variables. All other information about the vector can be calculated from those two numbers. To begin the declaration of the class:

```
class Physics_vector {

double x, y;

public:
// Constructors and member functions here...
...
```

You seem to have the constructor down: all it needs to do is initialize those two variables. However, we can add some additional functionality: what if we wanted to declare a `Physics_vector` without actually giving it a value yet? Well, then we could code the constructor to give `x` and `y` some reasonable default values when it's constructed without any values:

```
...
explicit Physics_vector(double x = 0, double y = 0):x(x), y(y) {}
...
```

The `explicit` keyword is to make sure that the constructor must be called explicitly, because in C++ a constructor that may take one argument also defines an implicit conversion from that argument to the class's type, and `Physics_vector vec = 0;` isn't a sensible conversion. Next, we'll need some way to access `x` and `y` from outside the class, so we'll make some getter and setter functions that access the two values:

```
...
double get_x() const {
    return x;
}

double get_y() const {
    return y;
}

void set_x(double x) {
    this->x = x;
}

void set_y(double y) {
    this->y = y;
}
...
```

Think of the `const` keyword as a promise you're making to the compiler that the member function won't modify any of the member variables. You may remove it and the class will still work, but it's usually best to put it in when it makes sense.

The syntax `this->x = x;` is necessary because x is declared twice in the scope of setter member functions: once in the function's arguments, and once in the classes member variables. The compiler isn't able to tell which is being referred to, so the C++ standard defines that the local declaration takes precedence. Therefore, trying to write `x = x;` will assign the function's argument `x` to itself. I noticed you did this by accident in your set_vector function (you assigned the member variable `force` to the function argument `f`, and the same thing for `m` and `magnitude`, and I don't think that's what you intended). The way to get around it is to use the `this` pointer (which is defined in member functions, constructors, and destructors, and always points to the current instance of the class).

Next, we'll define an add function, because it's sensible to code the addition of two `Physics_vector`s with the class. The function should take another `Physics_vector` and add it to `*this`, and return the result.

```
...
Physics_vector add(Physics_vector other) const {
    return Physics_vector(x + other.x, y + other.y);
}
...
```

Although this next part is more advanced (and may not have been covered in your class yet), I'll put it out there anyway. What if we wanted to add two `Physics_vector`s like we would two `double`s? In other words add `Physics_vector`s `vec1` and `vec2` like `Physics_vector result = vec1 + vec2;`. Well, C++ provides a way to define such an operation. We would code it like this:

```
...
Physics_vector operator + (Physics_vector other) const {
    return Physics_vector(x + other.x, y + other.y);
}
...
```

We can also add some other useful functions, such as a function that returns the magnitude of the `Physics_vector`.

```
...
double magnitude() const {
    return sqrt(x*x + y*y);
}
}; // End of the the declaration/definition of Physics_vector.
```

The `sqrt` function is defined in the header `cmath`, and computes the square root of its argument. The magical `std_lib_facilities_4.h` header you're including (probably created by your instructor for your convenience) may or may not have included cmath for you.

Given this class you can then implement your program like this:

```
int main()
{
    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    cout << "Please give two vectors to add.\n";
    cout << "x1: ";
    cin >> x1;
    cout << "\ny1: ";
    cin >> y1;
    cout << "\nx2: ";
    cin >> x2;
    cout << "\ny2: ";
    cin >> y2;

    Physics_vector vec1(x1, y1);
    Physics_vector vec2(x2, y2);

    Physics_vector result = vec1.add(vec2); // Or vec1 + vec2, if you use the operator + overload I described.

    cout << "\n\nvec1 + vec2 = ("
         << result.get_x() << ", "
         << result.get_y() << ")";
}
```

Hope that helps you with your programmer's block!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should probably improve your understanding of C++ classes in general. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) is a good place to start. I'll try to give you a few pointers though.

1. Assuming your vector class only needs to store two values you have
   way to many member variables. You actually only need two doubles:
   force and magnitude (do you mean magnitude and direction?). The
   variables of type `vector` are unnecessary, as despite its name, an
   [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) is only a dynamic array.
2. You don't need a separate `set_vector()` method as you are already
   setting the values for your vector in the constructor by passing
   force and magnitude values in there. On the other hand you may want
   to add accessors for the member variables as `get_force()` and
   `get_magnitude()` as well as perhaps `set_force()` and
   `set_magnitude()` if you think you may want to change these values
   from outside.
3. For adding the vectors you should use operator overloading and
   implement a method called `operator+` which will let you you easily
   add two vectors together by simply typing something like `v3 = v1 + v2`.
4. This is mostly a matter of style and its not necessary, but I'd
   suggest you to add some kind of prefix to your member variables, so
   they are easily distinguished from local variables in the code. A
   popular convention is to use `m_variable`. Also listing your public
   members first, generally makes class interface slightly easier to
   read.

With all the above in mind your vector interface could look like this (I'll leave the implementation to you):

```
class PhysicsVector
{
public:
    PhysicsVector(double force, double magnitude) : m_force(force), m_magnitude(magnitude) 
    {
    }

    double getForce() const;
    double getMagnitude() const;
    void setForce(double force);
    void setMagnitude(double magnitude);

    PhysicsVector operator+(PhysicsVector other) const;

private:
    double m_force, m_magnitude;
}
```